# Preferred architecture for running a separate process

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, architecture

I'm wondering what the preferred architecture would be for the following situation:

I'm required to have a .NET application that will perform batch upload of multiple data files concurrently to a SQL Server. This will be invoked from a WPF application which will allow the user to select the files and the destination tables, as well as reporting on the individual progress for each upload (including error messages). I have absolutely no problem writing the code for any of this. However, there is a requirement that the user is able to close the WPF application altogether and for the upload process to continue. Further, if the user restarts the WPF application from the same machine, it should be able to get a handle on the existing uploads and report on the status as if the program were never closed.

My question is what are the ways of achieving this and which would seem the most standard/suitable?

I've considered simply not actually closing the WPF application but hiding all the windows, but this seems a cheat. Would it be best to create a WCF service on the server where the upload is taking place and simply upload the file? I don't think I can do that and report progress % etc though. What about a locally-running Windows Service, can I achieve a similar effect? Should I be thinking of MemoryMappedFiles?

Appreciate all your thoughts.

Comment: Currently in work I devised a solution for a similar problem; we had a web interface that had to perform a time-consuming task. I ended up making the web interface write a request to a MsSQL database (which it already had anyway) and have a windows service poll for new requests and handle them every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are talking about long-running task, I would use local Windows Service communicating with your WPF application through MSMQ. For example, each file to upload can be represented by one MSMQ message. Your WPF application will be putting messages into queue and Windows Service, periodically and without any impact if WPF is running or not, should take it from queue and process. This will provide simple and reliable channel of providing tasks (uploads).

To provide internal status of the Windows Service to its clients (your WPF application), I would host inside it a WCF endpoint with simple service that is telling, for example, about progress.

Comment: You got it spot on for my needs. Plus, this means the Windows Service could be migrated to a server rather than the local machine, with little effort.